Find all functions that satisfy $x^2f(x) = f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$
Can we find all functions that satisfy the following properties:

$f$ has domain $(0,\infty)$
$f \in C^{\infty} (0,\infty)$
$f(1) = 1$
$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \infty$
$\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ converges
$x^2f(x) = f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

The reason why I would like to find all functions is that the function with the described properties satisfies:
$$ \displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \displaystyle\int_1^{\infty} f(x) dx$$
and hence
$$ \displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$$
Which can be proven with the substitution $u = \frac{1}{x}$
I have not been able to find one yet. $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ satisfies all the properties except the integral convergence property, which is the closest I have got.

The functions $f_n(x) = \frac{2 + \log^{2 n} x}{1 + x^2}$, where $n$ is a positive integer, seem to do the trick.

Note that the same integral relation may be obtained with other changes of variables, such as $x = -\ln t$ together with the functional equation $tf(t) = f(-\ln t)$ for instance.

Since $xf(x)=\frac{1}{x}f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, does not that mean there is a inversion symmetry, which means $x$ can be replaced with $\frac{1}{x}$ anytime? I might be wrong anyway...

We'll first address the general problem of describing the functions $f : \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$ satisfying the functional equation
$$x^2 f(x) = f\left(\frac1x\right),$$
and then we'll translate the additional requirements into the setting of that description.
As in Greg Martin's comment, in terms of $g(x) := x f(x)$ the relation $x^2 f(x) = f\left(\frac1{x}\right)$ simplifies to
$$g(x) = g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),$$ but this condition is equivalent to $h = g \circ \exp : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ being even. So, for any even function $h : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$,
$$\boxed{f(x) = \frac{h(\log x)}{x}}$$
satisfies the functional equation, and all functions $f$ satisfying the functional equation arise this way.
In terms of $h$ the condition on the limit as $x \to 0$ can be written as $\lim_{u \to +\infty} e^u h(u) = +\infty$, which informally just means that that $h(u)$ decays more slowly than $\exp$ grows as $u \to +\infty$. Since $\lim_{u \to +\infty} e^u \operatorname{sech} u = 1$, it's convenient to write $h(u) = p(u) \operatorname{sech} u$ (necessarily $p$ is even), in which case the limit condition becomes $\lim_{u \to +\infty} p(u) = +\infty$. In terms of $p$,
$$\boxed{f(x) = \frac{2 p(\log x)}{1 + x^2}} ,$$
and again all $f$ satisfying the functional equation have this form.
Straightforward calculation translates the remaining conditions on $f$ into conditions on $h$ and $p$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
f & h & p \\
\hline
  f(1) = 1
& h(0) = 1
& p(0) = 1\\
  \textrm{$f$ is integrable}
& \textrm{$h$ is integrable}
& \textrm{$u \mapsto e^{-u} p(u)$ is integrable on $\Bbb R^+$} \\
  \lim_{x \searrow  0     }     f(x) = +\infty
& \lim_{u \to      +\infty} e^u h(u) = +\infty
& \lim_{u \to      +\infty}     p(u) = +\infty \\
  f \in C^{\infty}(\Bbb R^+)
& h \in C^{\infty}(\Bbb R)
& p \in C^{\infty}(\Bbb R) \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Note that the condition that $u \mapsto e^{-u} p(u)$ is integrable on $\Bbb R^+$ can be rephrased as saying that the Laplace transform $\mathcal L\{p\}(s)$ of $p$ is defined at $s = 1$.
Example If $p$ is an even polynomial, then $f(0) = 1$ if and only if the constant term of $p$ is $1$, the limit condition holds if and only if $p$ is not constant, and the differentiability and integrability conditions always hold.
Example One can produce algebraic functions $f$ satisfying the conditions by taking, for example, $p(u) = \cosh a u$, $a \in \Bbb Q \cap (-1, 1)$, which gives rise to
$$f(x) = \frac{x^a + \frac1{x^a}}{1 + x^2};$$
then $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a + \frac1{x^a}}{1 + x^2} \,dx = \pi \sec \frac{\pi a}{2}$.

is the $f(\frac1{x^2})$ correct in your answer?

No, that's a typo---I've corrected it, and the rest of the answer is unaffected.
